# jQuery Sortable in tab content moved to another content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I am trying to do jQuery sortable with items to be moved from tab contents to another div. It it working mostly fine, but the problem I am having is that I would like the item to be back to tab from which it was taken.

So let say that I have got tabs:

- Shipping Address with items:

  - Street 1
  - Street 2
  - City
  - Country
- Attributes with items:

  - Industry
  - Types
  - Full Name

The tab content is taking 50% of width on left and 50% of width on right is the div block to were I want to drop the items. If I would like to remove the item from div block, it should come back to the related tab, so e.g. Industry cannot go back to Shipping Addres , it needs to go to Attributes.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/epxp5L48/

The screen how it looks like
[image]
My HTML code:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
            <li class="active"><a href="#Attributes" data-toggle="tab">Attributes</a></li>
            <li><a href="#InvoiceAddress" data-toggle="tab">InvoiceAddress</a></li>
            <li><a href="#ShippingAddress" data-toggle="tab">ShippingAddress</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div id="fields-draggable" class="tab-content">
            <div class="tab-pane connectedSortable ui-sortable active" id="Attributes">
                <button id="field_industry" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block ui-sortable-handle">industry</button>
                <button id="field_types" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block ui-sortable-handle">types</button>
                <button id="field_full_name" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block ui-sortable-handle">full_name</button>
            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane connectedSortable ui-sortable" id="InvoiceAddress">
                <button id="field_street1" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block ui-sortable-handle">street1</button>
                <button id="field_street2" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block ui-sortable-handle">street2</button>
                <button id="field_id" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block ui-sortable-handle">id</button>
                <button id="field_street3" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block ui-sortable-handle">street3</button>
                <button id="field_postcode" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block ui-sortable-handle">postcode</button>
                <button id="field_city" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block ui-sortable-handle">city</button>
                <button id="field_stateId" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block ui-sortable-handle">stateId</button>
                <button id="field_countryId" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block ui-sortable-handle">countryId</button>
                </div>
            <div class="tab-pane connectedSortable ui-sortable" id="ShippingAddress">
                <button id="field_id" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block ui-sortable-handle">id</button>
                <button id="field_street1" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block ui-sortable-handle">street1</button>
                <button id="field_street2" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block ui-sortable-handle">street2</button>
                <button id="field_street3" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block ui-sortable-handle">street3</button>
                <button id="field_postcode" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block ui-sortable-handle">postcode</button>
                <button id="field_city" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block ui-sortable-handle">city</button>
                <button id="field_stateId" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block ui-sortable-handle">stateId</button>
                <button id="field_countryId" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block ui-sortable-handle">countryId</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">
        <div id="fields-sortable" class="connectedSortable well ui-sortable" style="min-height: 40px;">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and jQuery UI code:

```
$("#fields-sortable, #Attributes" ).sortable({
    connectWith: ".connectedSortable",
    placeholder: "btn btn-default btn-lg btn-block",
    cancel: ''
});
$("#fields-sortable, #InvoiceAddress" ).sortable({
    connectWith: ".connectedSortable",
    placeholder: "btn btn-default btn-lg btn-block",
    cancel: ''
});
$("#fields-sortable, #ShippingAddress" ).sortable({
    connectWith: ".connectedSortable",
    placeholder: "btn btn-default btn-lg btn-block",
    cancel: ''
});
$( "#fields-sortable" ).sortable({
    update: function (event, ui) {
        var data = $(this).sortable( "serialize");
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

Comment: It would be better if you create a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) of your code.

Comment: @chipChocolate.py thanks, I have added now the url to Fiddle

Comment: *"If I would like to remove the item from div block, it should come back to the related tab"* - How are you planning to remove the item..?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have managed to do it by adding the `data-tab-id` attribute to the buttons and adding `over` event to the sortable

```
over: function(event, ui) {
    var overId = $(this).attr('id');
    var elementId = $(event.toElement).data('tab-id');
    if(overId != "fields-sortable" && overId != elementId) {
        var aClick = $("#nav-types").find('a[href="#' + elementId + '"]');
        aClick.click();
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `#nav-types`..? what does `aClick.click();`? where is the corresponding handler..? this solution is totally useless for future readers unless you include the full code and explain what you did...